# The current user does not have write access to this item. User: sitecore\JssImport,

Tags: jss

I am trying to setup the Sitecore JSS,getting error when executing the command.

```
jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary
```

> Skipping data update of /sitecore/content because item already exists and is not writable by import user.
>   Exception thrown while importing JSS app
>   Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
>   Message: The current user does not have write access to this item. User: sitecore\JssImport, Item: ContentBlock ({1C0AA103-5BE5-5A08-9403-C6C36670C4B9})
>   Source: Sitecore.Kernel
>      at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.BeginEdit()
>      at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Datasources.AppLevelDatasourceStrategy.ConfigureDatasourceFolder(RenderingDef rendering, Item folder, IdManager idManager, AppConfiguration app)
>      at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Datasources.AppLevelDatasourceStrategy.GetDatasourceLocations(RenderingDef rendering, AppConfiguration app, IdManager idManager)
>      at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Datasources.AggregateDatasourceStrategy.GetDatasourceLocations(RenderingDef rendering, AppConfiguration app, IdManager idManager)
>      at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Pipelines.Import.ProcessRenderings.CreateRendering(RenderingDef renderingDef, ImportPipelineArgs args, IdManager idManager, AppConfiguration app, IDatasourceStrategy datasourceStrategy)
>      at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Pipelines.Import.ProcessRenderings.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(RenderingDef rendering)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
>      at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Pipelines.Import.ProcessRenderings.Process(ImportPipelineArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>      at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Pipelines.Import.ImportPipeline.Import(ImportPipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.ImportService.ImportJob.StartImportInternal()

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error was mainly because of the Javascript services - SitecorePath was mentioned wrongly.

I suppose to leave it as 'sitecore/content/myapp', but i changed to ''sitecore/content/' thinking that it needs to be changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be happened if you deployed your JSS application to the Sitecore and then made the changes at page level in Sitecore and for that, the respective items are not in correct workflow and JSS expecting them in specific workflow.
To solve this, go to the User manager and find the User - JssImport and make that user as Administrator.