# Sitecore JSS update content item

Tags: sitecore-client, jss, sitecore-api, jss-rendering-sdk

I have created a hello world JSS application with Angular + Rest application. I have deployed the application to my local sitecore 10.3.

Later, i have created a new component and i am able to add the component in the page and then i tried to deploy the application to sitecore with the command "**jss deploy app -c -d**", I got the below warning while importing item is happening.

"**Skipping data update of /sitecore/content/jss-app-demo/home because item already exists and is not writable by import user.**"

Also, i have noticed that the new component has been included in the config file "**\sitecore\manifest\sitecore-import.json**".

Is this something related to the permission? or how to update the item (adding new component) which is already in sitecore? If this is related to permission how/where to provide the permission?

Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JssImport` service is unable to create/update an item under `Content` item. So this is the permission problem. You can use 2 approaches here.

1. Provide access to user `sitecore\JssImport` to `Sitecore\Content` and its descendant items as

   [image]
2. Go to the User Manager and find the User `JssImport` and make it `Administrator`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Sumit. For some reason the import user was disabled. I have enabled it and made the user as administrator. It works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Sitecore document, For the import to work, your JSS import user must have the correct permissions. To make sure the user has the right permissions, go to the Content Editor, open the Content item, and click the Security, Assign like below. In the Assign Security Rights dialog, select the `sitecore\JssImport` user, and make sure they have write permissions to both Items and Descendants.

[image]

Reference: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/import-a-jss-app-into-your-headless-site.html

On the other hand, if that is not solving your issue, then you can refer to this thread that shows the issue of Javascript services - SitecorePath.

[The current user does not have write access to this item. User: sitecore\JssImport,](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/the-current-user-does-not-have-write-access-to-this-item-user-sitecore-jssimpo)

Hope this will solve your issue.